# Is AVMetadataFaceObject available in OS X 10.10 or not?

Tags: macos, avfoundation

I'm desperately trying to learn and implement the `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` object type which Apple has documentation [for here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureMetadataOutput/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureMetadataOutput):

But you can see that on that page all of the code types are crossed out, saying they're only available in OS X 10.9.  But that method seems like it is a pre-requisite for implementing `AVMetadataFaceObject` which is only available in OS X 10.10 - [per this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataFaceObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012226-CH1-SW10):

I'm very confused and don't know why they (Apple) would introduce a new feature but require a method which has been depreciated for it to work.

Now my code is just throwing out **"not available on OS X"** errors and I don't know where to turn. Have I completely missed something and can anyone help?

Quoting OP in comment:

*"also sorry for calling things the wrong names - perhaps when I'm typing like this I should just call things "things" rather than randomly guessing at "object" "type" "method" etc."*

Comment: also sorry for calling things the wrong names - perhaps when I'm typing like this I should just call things "things" rather than randomly guessing at "object" "type" "method" etc.  Still learning this stuff

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my post Unheilig, I'll try to take that example into my future posts. Just an honest question - why did you move my comment into the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Use Core Image’s `CIDetector` and `CIQRCodeFeature` classes.  They’ll find and decode the information and even correct for rotation and perspective issues.

([Source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7856))